# onfocus event triggered multiple times in Internet explorer

Tags: javascript, events, onfocus

The code is to add some access keys to some buttons present on the page. The interface is like this:
main page with some accordion tabs lets say accordion_A , accordion_B and accordion_C, there is a button A in let us say 'accordion_A' tab, for that button A , a hot key(for example: ALT+D) is added so pressing that will invoke that button associated function.

```
    if ( _browser.isIE )
        text += " href='javascript:void(0)'" +
                " onfocus='KeyPressed(\"" + key + "\")'></A>";
     else
        text += " href='Javascript:KeyPressed(\"" + key + "\")'></A>";
```

First the page is opened and let us suppose accordion_C is the default tab, now I go to accordion_A, now the hotkeys are added to the buttons present on accordion_A (deferred tab). Now I again go back to accordion_C and press 'ALT+D' to invoke the button present on accordion_A. The button function invokes and a popup is opened. The problem starts here, in IE when I close the popup, again the onfocus event is triggered, this will go on for like forever.

Is there any way to counter this phenomenon, Thanks for reading, hoping i am clear.

Comment: the rest of the code would be nice... maybe the problem is that after closing the popup focus returns to the last element. if that's the case you'd have to come up with a way to deregister the focus event on focus and then re-register it on blur. stil... without the rest of the code there's not much more I can do to help

Comment: yes, that seems to be the problem, however if i am in the same tab as the button and invoke alt+d and close the popup, it was not appearing again.I will see if i can get the additional code.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this inside your KeyPressed function

```
 event.cancelBubble = true;
 if (event.stopPropagation) event.stopPropagation();
```

Comment: Thanks will try out the suggestion

Comment: If this didn't work, please post all of your code if possible.